How can I make a powershell script work in an Azure function with PowerShell 5 and module AzureADPreview?
How can I make this PowerShell script work in an Azure function? This script is using the PowerShell module "AzureADPreview" and works only in PowerShell 5.
Write-Host "START"

Connect-AzureAD -identity
$disabledUsers = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "AccountEnabled eq false" | Select UserPrincipalName

foreach($disabledUser in $disabledUsers) {
    $logs = Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "targetResources/any(tr:tr/userPrincipalName eq '$($disabledUser.UserPrincipalName)' and ActivityDisplayName eq 'Disable account')" -Top 1 | select ActivityDateTime 
    if($logs) {
        foreach ($log in $logs) {
            if($log.ActivityDateTime.DateTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-5).DateTime) {
                write-host "Account $($disabledUser.UserPrincipalName) disabled more as 5 days ago. Logs found."
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        write-host "Account $($disabledUser.UserPrincipalName) disabled more as 30 days ago. Cannot find logs."
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
}

Write-Host "FINISH"


Could you include what error you are facing when you run it in Azure Function?

Note that, AzureADPreview only works with Windows PowerShell 5.1, not with PowerShell Core Edition (v6.x, v7.x). However, Azure Functions only offer PowerShell Core (v7.2, v7.4), so there's a conflict.
Alternatively, you can migrate to Microsoft Graph PowerShell module that works in PowerShell Core for retrieving same results.
I created one function app named demofunc1811 with below properties:

Enable system-assigned managed identity in above function app and add required permissions to this service principal. You can refer this SO thread for the same:

Make sure to add below dependencies in requirements.psd1 file of App files and restart the Azure Function App:
# This file enables modules to be automatically managed by the Functions service.
# See https://aka.ms/functionsmanageddependency for additional information.
#
@{
    'Microsoft.Graph.Authentication' = '2.19.0'
    'Microsoft.Graph.Reports' = '2.19.0'
    'Microsoft.Graph.Users' = '2.19.0' 
}

Now, I created one HTTP Trigger Function and replaced run.ps1 with below sample code and got the response successfully:
using namespace System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

# Write a simple message for testing
$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

# Connect to Microsoft Graph using Managed Identity
Write-Host "Connecting to Microsoft Graph..."
Connect-MgGraph -Identity

Get-MgContext 

# Retrieve disabled users from Azure AD
Write-Host "Retrieving disabled users..."
$disabledUsers = Get-MgUser -Filter "accountEnabled eq false" | Select-Object UserPrincipalName

# Iterate through disabled users and check activity logs
foreach ($disabledUser in $disabledUsers) {
    $logs = Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter "targetResources/any(tr:tr/userPrincipalName eq '$($disabledUser.UserPrincipalName)' and activityDisplayName eq 'Disable account')" -Top 1

    if ($logs) {
        foreach ($log in $logs) {
            $disabledDate = [DateTime]$log.ActivityDateTime
            $currentDate = (Get-Date)

            if ($disabledDate -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) {
                Write-Host "Account $($disabledUser.UserPrincipalName) was disabled today."
                break
            }
            elseif ($disabledDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)) {
                Write-Host "Account $($disabledUser.UserPrincipalName) disabled more than 5 days ago. Logs found."
                break
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Account $($disabledUser.UserPrincipalName) disabled more than 30 days ago. Cannot find logs."
    }
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})

Response:


Thanks, how does your profile.ps1 looks like?

My profile.ps1 has nothing, commented all...Check this https://i.imgur.com/kXGK24R.png

Hi @KEM Any update on this?

It i working fine, thank you very much for your help
